# Serving simultaneous/concurrent requests in my server handler?

Tags: netty

I'm currently writing a proxy server using netty (which is a wonderful framework!). I would appreciate some advice/comments on an issue I'm currently dealing with:

My proxy server is redirecting HTTP requests to web server, X. The web server then sends an HTTP response back to the proxy server which in turn forwards the response off to the appropriate client.

This currently works fine with a single client issuing the requests. However, when a second client starts, the channelRead of the proxy server handler receives response data sequentially from the web server. Hence, if it's currently receiving a stream of data for one request, the second request issued by the second client must block until the first is complete.

I just wanted to ask if there is a recommended way to execute this concurrently?

I would appreciate any guidance.

Thank you!

Comment: why must it block ? Can you clarify ?

Comment: Norman! I never would have that you would comment! 
Yes, please let me clarify:

The current behavior is that the response to the second requests blocks until the first request has been completely served. My aim is to serve both requests simultaneously. The proxy server has one server handler with a channelRead implementation which only receives the response data from the web server one after the other. The requests were written to this server channel. 

Please let me know if you require any further clarification. Thank you!

Comment: Basically, I would appreciate any guidance as to how I can restructure my proxy server design such that I can proxy requests to a single web server and receive response streams simultaneously to return back to the appropriate clients.

Thank you! I appreciate your time!